# Delete list of files from Visual Studio project and TFS

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs

I want to delete all unused images from asp.net project. I have found 85 unused files. Is there any automatic approach to delete all these files from project and from TFS source control?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a plug-in that would probably give you the facility to have a file as input that lists files to be deleted, and action those.

It will probably take you longer to write than it would just to manually delete them.

It's Friday. Chill out and click/confirm the mouse 85 times.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it have sense